# Modifying the values in JSON Object and putting it into another JSON Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I  am trying to update the existing json Object in the following way without using any functions in plain java script.This is asked in one of the interviews.

Attached is my Input file:

```
{

  "height_c": 534,
  "width_c": "800",
  "height_h": 1067,
  "width_h": "1600",
  "height_k": 1366,
  "width_k": "2048",
  "height_l": "683",
  "width_l": "1024",
  "height_m": "333",
  "width_m": "500",
  "height_n": 213,
  "width_n": "320",
  "height_q": "150",
  "width_q": "150",
  "height_s": "160",
  "width_s": "240",
  "height_sq": 75,
  "width_sq": 75,
  "height_t": "67",
  "width_t": "100",
  "height_z": "427",
  "width_z": "640"

}
```

Attached is my Expected file:

```
{
   "sizes": {
    "c": {
    "width": 800,
    "height": 534
    },
    "h": {
    "width": 1600,
    "height": 1067
    },
    "k": {
    "width": 2048,
    "height": 1366
    },
    "l": {
    "width": 1024,
    "height": 683
    },
    "m": {
    "width": 500,
    "height": 333
    },
    "n": {
    "width": 320,
    "height": 213
    },
    "q": {
    "width": 150,
    "height": 150
    },
    "s": {
    "width": 240,
    "height": 160
    },
    "q": {
    "width": 75,
    "height": 75
    },
    "t": {
    "width": 100,
    "height": 67
    },
    "z": {
    "width": 640,
    "height": 427
    }
}
}
```

Any Help would be appreciated.I am looking for a starting point.

Comment: functions are first class citizen in plain Javascript

Comment: I suspect `without using any functions` actually meant `without using any 3rd party modules/libs.` Without functions you wouldn't even be able to get the first json string, and you wouldn't be able to modify it if you did.

Comment: @KevinB Yes....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var input = {
  "height_c": 534,
  "width_c": "800",
  "height_h": 1067,
  "width_h": "1600",
  "height_k": 1366,
  "width_k": "2048",
  "height_l": "683",
  "width_l": "1024",
  "height_m": "333",
  "width_m": "500",
  "height_n": 213,
  "width_n": "320",
  "height_q": "150",
  "width_q": "150",
  "height_s": "160",
  "width_s": "240",
  "height_sq": 75,
  "width_sq": 75,
  "height_t": "67",
  "width_t": "100",
  "height_z": "427",
  "width_z": "640"
}

var output = {}

for (var key in input) {
  var split = key.split('_')
  if (!output[split[1]]) output[split[1]] = {};
  output[split[1]][split[0]] = input[key];
}

document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify({sizes: output}, null, 4)));
```

```css
body { white-space: pre; font-family: monospace; }
```